# Is there software that will allow me to mount a bootable USB stick as a DVD drive?

Tags: vmware, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootable-media, virtual-drive

I have made a bootable USB stick which successfully installs Windows 7.

I'd also like to use it with VM Ware, which only recognises DVD drives.

Can I mount my bootable USB drive to emulate being a DVD drive?

Comment: Check this article from [How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/97923/how-to-boot-a-vmware-virtual-machine-from-a-usb-drive/). It's a little bit of a hack, but it should work for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, is the answer I seem to have found. Not without using an ISO image.

Comment: Maybe it can be tricked by having a symlink with somefilename.iso pointing to the device node name of the USB stick.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. But you can create an ISO image from it using [ISORecorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm), then mount it with a tool like [Virtual Clonedrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) to achieve the same effect.

Comment: You can mount the ISO directly as a DVD drive in VMWare, no need of Virtual CloneDrive.

Comment: Yup. doesn't hurt to have a virtual DVD drive on the host though, they come in very handy.

Comment: Yeh, I had already tried that but I couldn't find a way to extract the "bootable" part of the USB stick. ISORecorder doesn't seem to do this unless I'm missing something..

Comment: Try using `dd` from a Linux liveCD, isorecorder probably can't grab the boot information as you said.

Comment: the "bootable" part of the USB stick isn't the same as the "bootable" part of a CD/DVD (different sector sizes, for one thing).  even if you manage to copy the boot stuff off the USB stick, a CD-emulator probably won't be able to boot from it.  you need to create a bootable CD version of your USBstick (just burn to ISO instead of an actual disc).